# How to select all parcels of a street? [ArcGIS Server]

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I have an Arcgis Server Map Service with a `Street` layer and a `Parcel` layer, I need to get the info of each parcel of a street that is selected by the user, does anyone knows how to do that? I'm a little bit lost. I'm using Arcgis Server 9.3, Visual Studio 2008 with Web ADF for .NET, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how good are the relative topologies of street and parcels you might want to:

- buffer the selected street and find out which parcels instersect, if the topology is not reliable;
- perform a spatial join (intersect would work I think) between the two feature classes if the topology is reliable.

Both these operations can be encapsulated in a geoprocessing service if you need to access the results through HTTP.

Comment: Hi GuillaumeC, I've been trying to use a buffer, but all the examples of buffers at the esri website dont work for me, could you explain to me how to perform a buffer?

Comment: Use the buffer tool in the Analysis toolbox in ArcMap:http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000.htm If it doesn't work, please be specific in describing the problem.